jQuery replace multiple img URL on page load
I have limited/basic knowledge of jQuery and even less of programming.
I have a page which loads content dynamically (I don’t control that content) to which I have enough permissions to load some jQuery code.
The page loads with a number of different images which have a path similar to /user1/resized/image1.jpg or /user2/resized/image2.jpg which I want to replace with /user1/original/image1.jpg and/user2/original/image2.jpg
So it needs to find all of the resized URLs and change them to the original URLs for multiple users and images.
How can I do that?
I am able to replace the image for one specific user but I do not know how to make the replace loop and dynamically (via regex?) find all/any users.

try this on page load, if there is no more img tags in page, if you have more img tags, then replace jQuery('.class img') instead of jQuery('img')
$(function() {
jQuery('img').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace("resized/", "original/"));
});

});

Thank you @qaisar-mahmood. This is great. How would I make the user part a variable too? Because in actuality “user.1” of the resized path needs to become “user-1” in the original path.
